# How to save a mesh Object as SVG format in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, export

When I have an mesh object in illustrator and export it as SVG, it gets saved as a base64 encoded png pixel image inside the svg.

How can I make an export of a mesh object as pure svg, so no pixels or encoded pixels but instead, paths?

Comment: 4 years passed... They still don't support it (

Comment: Probably wont. SVG is not really getting any features anymore as most implementers arent really happy to expand scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not. SVG is not currently supporting mesh primitives, though hopes are that it will soon do so, all it needs is a few more SVG implementations to implement this.